# How to validate Unique username to all users in Flutter social media app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am creating a Memer social media app. So in this everything is ready but I am confused in providing Unique display name for all users. User name are given by users. But how to validate that it is really present or not? All data are stored in firebase cloud firestore. So can anybody can help me?
Username is stored is like this: collection "users" -> document "userId" ->field  "username"

Comment: To register user. Aren't you using user authentication provided by firebase itself?

Comment: when you are going to register then make another collection named "username". then you can check username is unique or not.

Comment: @NaveenRao  Yes but also providing username to all users. which is saved cloud firestore

Comment: @JewelRana but how to check? can you please share more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I made a new collection with the name username. And before creating the account i was calling this function to check availability:-

```
checkUsernameIsUnique(String username)async
  {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
    setState(() {
      loading=true;
    });
    querySnapshot=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('username').where("username",isEqualTo: username).getDocuments();
    print(querySnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty);
    return querySnapshot.documents.isEmpty;
  }

checkUsernameIsUnique('username to be checked').then((val){
if(val)
{
   //create the user and store the username in username collection also
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('username').document(widget.username).setData({
        "username":widget.username,
      });
}
else 
//username is taken
});
```

Comment: Their is a error. The method 'where' is not defined for the type 'Storage Refrence'

Answer (score 0):

u can create `cloud function` which will get username and returns bool if its unique or not.

Comment: Aren't cloud functions async?

Comment: yes u can use debounce function for checking if its unique or not as user is typing in textfield